# How to get date without the browser timestamp?

Tags: javascript

Hi I was wondering if there was any way to get a Date in javascript without the browser timestamp appended to it. So I just want the date 3/5/2014 and should be the same from anywhere else in the world.

Any ideas?

I tried setting the hours to (0,0,0,0) but it still gives me a GMT time of 8:00

date.setHours(0,0,0,0);

Thank you

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `date.setUTCHours(0)`

Alternatively, if you're just working with the date, set the UTC hours to 12, as this will ensure that wherever you are in the world the date will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you maybe explain the difference between setting it to 0 and 12? Also I tried it in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_setutchours
but it was still GMT-8 does this matter?

Comment: Erm... 0 is midnight, 12 is midday. But when it's midday in UTC, it's the same date everywhere in the world. The date object will always be output in your timezone - that's why I use the `getUTC*` functions :)

Answer (score 2):

[MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/) is a nice library for handling dates. If you're just trying to display the date you'd be looking for the [Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method to specify exactly how you want it printed. eg:

```
moment(new Date(2011, 9, 16)).format('YYYY MM DD');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure to get that result, the best way is doing it manually:

```
var d = new Date();
d = d.getUTCMonth()+'/'+d.getUTCDay()+'/'+d.getUTCFullYear();
```

(Assuming that your example 3/5/2014 corresponds to 5th March 2014)

Answer (score 1):

The "current date" is only meaningful at a specific location — or at least, within a specific timezone.  You can't get a single date that's correct all around the world, because the current date is actually different in different parts of the world.

For example:  if it's 3AM on March 6, 2014 in Greenwich, it's 10PM on March 5, 2014 on the US East Coast.